# php settings per virtualhost not working

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

I've got virtual host for each environment of application. In each one there are settings for php to set proper error reporting. On new machine I've set php 5.6 and now I can't set `error_reporting` and `display_errors` as I wish.

```
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag display_errors off
php_value error_reporting 8191
php_value error_log d:/httpd/logs/app/php.error.log
```

It doesn't stops php from reporting DEPRECATED and displaying errors to user. The only setting working is `error_log`.

Comment: what's the output of `phpinfo()` for those settings?

Comment: Try setting `error_reporting` to a value like `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` or use the function `error_reporting()` with the same value.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon display_errors is On (for local and global) and error_reporting is 32759 for local and 32767 for global

Comment: is yours a dedicated server? some hosting services blocks you to change some settings. BTW, it sounds strange that errors cannot be disabled in a production environment. What if you create a page with only

`ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
error_reporting(0);
phpinfo();` ?

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon It is on local server to which I have full access. Setting it in php code works fine. I need to set those per server to not mess in code shared via repo.

Comment: be sure to have "AllowOverride Options" or "AllowOverride All" in your apache vhost configuration

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon yeah this is set to. What is funny, after turning all off in VirtualHost I've got different local and master settings in phpinfo and no additional ini files were parsed. .htaccess has no php settings at all.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out one of libraries sets error reporting to `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE` in its configuration file which is loaded in application Bootstrap. So when setting VirtualHost and some configs won't set check in code, because some idiot might have set it there environment independent.

Something to remember to is Zend application config file might hold some php config to. It is another place worth considering when searching.